cheapest ways to hedge
I would like to know what are my options in protecting my equity portfolio in the short term. I assume there are different costs involved in each. I own a number of ETFs and would like to protect myself from large losses in value in my portfolio. One way is to buy put options=insurance for the horizon I am trying to hedge. If the ETF price goes down the options will actually increase in value and I will make money. I will also have a floor with a strike I bought it for. Is there another way to hedge myself? All the personal finance books tell me to buy and hold a diversified portfolio but I am not comfortable to have its value drop below certain threshold so I would like to consider hedging.

Treasury bonds are good hedge against equity. It can be cheaper than put options.

Treasury bonds are cheaper than put options?  Huh?

Yes, "if the ETF price goes down the options will actually increase in value and I (you) will make money" on the puts.  However, you will lose more on the underlying plus the cost of the puts than you make on the protective put.  The nice thing about such appreciated puts (after the ETF tanks) is that you can either cash them in or roll them down, booking a nice gain, effectively lowering your cash at risk.

This question is similar to: How to make money from a downward European market?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.


All the personal finance books tell me to buy and hold a diversified portfolio but I am not comfortable to have its value drop below certain threshold so I would like to consider hedging.

Put options will provide a floor, but they also take away some of your upside - if your ETFs go up in value, the put options will lose value, negating some of the gain. They are used in hedging more for eliminating risk, not just for limiting losses.  Plus, you pay a premium for options (just like insurance), and the more protection you get, the more you have to pay upfront.
The cheapest way is to put in "stop loss" orders. Those will sell your positions if the price gets below a certain level. You'll then have to decide when (or if) to buy back in.
The main problem with stop loss orders is that they must be done per investment. You cannot, for example, put in an order to sell all of your positions if your total value goes below a certain level. With a diversified portfolio, some investments may go up while others go down, so you may have stop losses that hit even if your overall portfolio value has not gone down significantly. So you still need to monitor your positions carefully.
If that still sounds like too much risk for you, then you could settle for a less diversified portfolio in a few broad index funds, and put stop losses on those.

Some brokers offer combination orders where you combine multiple equities into one order, effectively, a self-created index.  You can then place a limit order on it.  However, I don't know the maximum number of legs allowed.

thanks for the answer. Stop loss definitely sounds simpler and perhaps I can define the cost. However, what are the benefits of option hedging? Even though it is more expensive there is something beneficial in it then?

Stop losses do not guarantee an exact price. if the price moves down quickly you may sell well below your stop price. They also execute immediately, realizing your loss even if the stock rebounds.  Put options guarantee a minimum price, and can survive a drop-and-rebound.

There are many ways to hedge and each one provide a different amount of protection and its cost varies.  Like auto or health insurance, with protective puts, the less you want to lose (the deductible), the more you have to pay for the protection.  That's the trade off. Buying puts for almost full protection is the most effective hedge but their cost is a lot of drag on a portfolio.
Covered calls provide a modest amount of protection.
Collared stock can be done for little to no cost but it requires capping the upside (the covered call pays for the long protective put).
Put LEAP spreads 10% out-of-the-money and 10% wide on ETFs are inexpensive but they don't protect as much of your portfolio as well as long puts do.
Even cheap OTM calendar spreads can be useful.
In short, you have to weigh the cost of the protection, the amount of protection it provides, and the opportunity cost, if any.
